# SQL. I need connect two row based on dates

Tags: mysql, sql, procedure

At the start i'm realy sorry for my bad english.

I need compare rows with the same id and if they are correct connect them:

```
  id  Date1       Date2         Date3     Date4
1210 2013-01-09    NULL     2018-04-10  2023-04-11
1210 2013-09-01 2018-10-04  2023-11-04     NULL
  83 2009-11-17    NULL     2014-11-30  2016-11-30
  83 2009-11-17    NULL        NULL     2016-11-30
 198 2008-04-22    NULL     2013-04-30  2015-04-30
 198 2008-04-22 2013-04-30  2014-04-30  2015-04-30
 198 2008-04-22    NULL        NULL        NULL
2070 1997-06-18    NULL     2002-09-30     N/A
2070 1997-06-18 2001-09-30  2002-09-30     NULL
2070 1997-06-18    NULL        NULL     2002-09-30
```

Rows from which I have already take data shoul be deleted.

Effect should be:

```
 id  Date1       Date2         Date3     Date4
1210 2013-01-09    NULL     2018-04-10  2023-04-11
1210 2013-09-01 2018-10-04  2023-11-04     NULL
  83 2009-11-17    NULL     2014-11-30  2016-11-30
 198 2008-04-22    NULL     2013-04-30  2015-04-30
 198 2008-04-22 2013-04-30  2014-04-30  2015-04-30
2070 1997-06-18 2001-09-30  2002-09-30  2002-09-30
```

1210 - Is unchanged because part of the date is different.

83 - are comparet then row with less data should be removed.

198 - Matched line data is assigned to the first matching line and the line is deleted. second line Is unchanged because part of the date is different.

2070 - All lines are merged into one. The attached lines are deleted.

I was tried make code:

```
 update tb  
 set tb.Date1 = case
                  when tj.Date1 is not null and (tb.Date1 is null or tb.Date1 = 'n/a')  then tj.Date1 end,
 tb.Date2 = case
                  when tj.Date2 is not null and (tb.Date2 is null or tb.Date2 = 'n/a') then tj.Date2 end,
 tb.Date3 = case
                  when tj.Date3 is not null and (tb.Date3 is null or tb.Date3 = 'n/a') then tj.Date3 end,
 tb.Date4 = case
                  when tj.Date4 is not null and (tb.Date4 is null or tb.Date4 = 'n/a') then tj.Date4    end 
from                                            
testcheck as tb inner join testcheck as tj on tb.Product_ID= tj.Product_ID
where (tb.Date1 = tj.Date1 or tb.Date1 is null or tj.Date1 is null or tb.Date1 = 'n/a' or tj.Date1 = 'n/a')
and (tb.Date2 = tj.Date2 or tb.Date2 is null or tj.Date2 is null or tb.Date2 = 'n/a' or tj.Date2 = 'n/a')
and (tb.Date3 = tj.Date3 or tb.Date3 is null or tj.Date3 is null or tb.Date3 = 'n/a' or tj.Date3 = 'n/a')
and (tb.Date4 = tj.Date4 or tb.Date4 is null or tj.Date4 is null or tb.Date4 = 'n/a' or tj.Date4 = 'n/a')
```

Comment: What is that `N/A` value doing in a date column?  Are you storing your dates as text?

Answer (score -1):

If I were in your situation, rather than trying to update the `testcheck` table, I would use a query to extract the data in the format I wanted, and then just insert that into a new table with the same structure:

```
CREATE TABLE newtestcheck (id int, Date1 datetime, Date2 datetime, Date3 datetime,
                           Date4 datetime);

INSERT INTO newtestcheck
SELECT id,
       Date1,
       MAX(Date2),
       MAX(Date3),
       MAX(Date4)
FROM testcheck
GROUP BY id, Date1;
```

After this, you can drop the original table and then possibly rename `newtestcheck` back to `testcheck` if you want.

**Note:** You have a very suspicious looking `N/A` data point in one of the date columns.  If literal, then it would mean you are storing your dates as text, and then my query would have to be modified.

Comment: What if two Date2's. Date3's or Date4's are different?